# Convert from string to UTC format

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app.
In this app I am working with dates.

I need all dates to be in UTC format. I am using this method to convert them:

```
public Date getConvertedUTCDate(String datetime) {

        Date myDate = null;

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

        try {

            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

            myDate = dateFormat.parse(datetime);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return myDate;

    }
```

But instead of getting the expected:

```
Sun Aug 10 14:13:14 UTC 2014
```

I get it in CEST format

```
Sun Aug 10 14:13:14 CEST 2014
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only set the `TimeZone` for the calendar of the parser. Not the `TimeZone` of the parsed result.